# Option value is not able to select using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a searchable dropdown and i want to select the option value which i am passing using this query:

```
$(#id).val('optiontext').attr('selected',true),
```

but every time it is typing in search text box inside dropdown, but ineed to select that option value.

Comment: Provide a fiddle please.

Comment: Its really hard to understand what you are trying to say!

Comment: instead of `attr` use `prop`.

Comment: Missing quotes around the id selector

Answer (score 0):

apart from missing quotes in id selector, you need to select option by text:

```
$("#id option").filter(function() {
  return this.text == 'optiontext'; 
}).attr('selected', true);​
```

Comment: `this.text` I haven't heard of this property before

Comment: i am doing same but it is  not selecting

Comment: @AdityaK: can you share fiddle with relevant code??